# How to create column to fill in an ID mapped from a smaller dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have two dataframes, one with lots of rows that include a `CategoryId` property that repeats, and the other dataframe only has two columns: `CategoryId` and `Category`:

```
print(map)
   CategoryId  Category
1  n013523     Snake
2  n012837     Iguana
3  n092735     Dragon

map.shape
(3, 2)


print(data)
   CategoryId  Size
1  n013523     0.4
2  n013523     0.8
3  n013523     0.15
4  n012837     0.16
5  n012837     0.23
6  n012837     0.42
...

data.shape
(500000, 2)
```

What I'd like to do is create a column on data that will have the value in `map['Category']` where `map['CategoryId'] == data['CategoryId']`, such that the output is:

```
print(data)
   CategoryId  Size  Category
1  n013523     0.4   Snake
2  n013523     0.8   Snake
3  n013523     0.15  Snake
4  n012837     0.16  Iguana
5  n012837     0.23  Iguana
6  n012837     0.42  Iguana
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) function as:

```
map.set_index('CategoryId',inplace=True)
data['Category'] = data['CategoryId'].map(map['Category'],na_action=np.nan)
```

Or using [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) as:

```
data = data.merge(map,how='left',on='CategoryId')
```

Or using `dict` and map:

```
data['Category'] = data.CategoryId.map(dict(map.values),na_action=np.nan)
```

Or using `dict` and replace this might give an error if dictionary `key` is not present.:

```
data['Category'] = data.CategoryId.replace(dict(map.values))
```

---

```
print(data)
      CategoryId  Size Category
    1    n013523  0.40    Snake
    2    n013523  0.80    Snake
    3    n013523  0.15    Snake
    4    n012837  0.16   Iguana
    5    n012837  0.23   Iguana
    6    n012837  0.42   Iguana
```